# Inserting small icon or figure in the margin left to some desired title in mdframed and mdfsetup

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed, fancybox

I need to insert some small icon or picture adjacent to a fancybox designed using mdframe as provided by [@Tom in textblog.org](https://texblog.org/2015/09/30/fancy-boxes-for-theorem-lemma-and-proof-with-mdframed/) using mdframe and tikz.

I could insert image using `includegraphics` inside the tikz and mdfsetup part of the code but that places image inside the box. But I need it to be outside the header box and placed at left side in the margin aligned with box.

The icon or picture will be of the adjustable height (for custom setup of height and width as per user)  and to be placed at the left side into margin at the start of the box. 
A sample of my design requirement is provided in the below demo picture
[image]

A MWE is copied here from the link already mentioned. Any slight modification or beautification of the design would be appreciated if provided separately with a slight explanation of command if possible so that I can understand the use of them as I am a learner and might use them later as per my need.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz} % I added this extra , are this necessary please comment 
\usepackage{pstricks} % I added this extra , are this necessary please comment 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Theorem
\newcounter{theo}[section] \setcounter{theo}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetheo}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theo}}
\newenvironment{theo}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{theo}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
{\strut Theorem~\thetheo};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
{\strut Theorem~\thetheo:~#1};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
linewidth=2pt,topline=true,%
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax
}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
\label{#2}}{\end{mdframed}}
\begin{document}
\section{Theorem and lemma examples with title}
\begin{theo}[Pythagoras' theorem]{thm:pythagoras}
In a right triangle, the square of the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the squares of the two other side.
\[a^2+b^2=c^2\]
\end{theo}
In mathematics, the Pythagorean theorem, also known as Pythagoras' theorem (see theorem \ref{thm:pythagoras}), is a relation in Euclidean geometry among the three sides of a right triangle.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you do not need to load `tikz` nor `pstricks`. `tikz` gets loaded since you say `framemethod=TikZ`, and pstrics is not needed here.

And yes, you can easily add something that runs into the margin by dialing the `overlay` option. I added some example image that is left of the title of the theorem title. For better positioning, I load the positioning library, which is not absolutely necessary but arguably convenient.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Theorem
\newcounter{theo}[section] \setcounter{theo}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetheo}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theo}}
\newenvironment{theo}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{theo}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
{\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20] (theo)
{\strut Theorem~\thetheo};
\node[left=0.4cm of theo,anchor=east,overlay]{
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-duck}};}}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
{\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20] (theo)
{\strut Theorem~\thetheo:~#1};
\node[left=0.4cm of theo,anchor=east,overlay]{
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-duck}};}}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
linewidth=2pt,topline=true,%
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax
}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
\label{#2}}{\end{mdframed}}
\begin{document}
\section{Theorem and lemma examples with title}
\begin{theo}[Pythagoras' theorem]{thm:pythagoras}
In a right triangle, the square of the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the squares of the two other side.
\[a^2+b^2=c^2\]
\end{theo}
In mathematics, the Pythagorean theorem, also known as Pythagoras' theorem (see theorem \ref{thm:pythagoras}), is a relation in Euclidean geometry among the three sides of a right triangle.
\end{document}
```

[image]